# How to stop setInterval after mouse hasn't moved for 20 sec?

Tags: jquery, setinterval

How can I stop the setInterval function if the mouse hasn't moved for 20 seconds while hovering over the ".postimagepic" element? Do I have to use delay somewhere?

```
var timeoutid = 0;
$(".postimagepic").mousemove(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutid);
    var myInterval; 
    $(this).hover(function () {
        var link = $(this).attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1)[0];
        //$("h1").text(link);
        myInterval = setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'time.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'user':'<?php echo $_SESSION["login"] ?>',
                    'topost':link
                },
                success: function() {

                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    }, function () {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    });
});
```